# Cannot install laravel-notification-channels/clickatell

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification, clickatell

When I try to install the notification channel **laravel-notification-channels/clickatell** it gives me the error below.

How can I clear it?

```
    - Root composer.json requires laravel-notification-channels/clickatell ^0.1.4 -> satisfiable by laravel-notification-channels/clickatell[0.1.4].   
    - laravel-notification-channels/clickatell 0.1.4 requires illuminate/notifications ~5.5 || ~6.0 || ~7.0 -> found illuminate/notifications[v5.5.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

Comment: what is version composer and laravel ?

Comment: Laravel 8.44 and composer 2.0 @ShokryMohamed

Comment: try this code
```
sudo composer require laravel-notification-channels/clickatell

```

Comment: if not working you must downgrade composer to version 1 with this code 
```
sudo composer self-update --1

```